# How to add non-commented code blocks to numbered documentation sections

Tags: c++, documentation, comments, doxygen

I need to produce documentation that has a numbered list of reference blocks that contains a tag, an incrementing number, and a real block of code (preferably with links). I can deal with at minimum a tag, unique number, and a real block of code.

So take this:

**C++ code**:

```
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    int c, d;
    /**
     * @method{} Multiply
     */
    c = a*b;
    /** @endmethod */
    /**
     * @method{} Divide
     */
    d = a/b;
    /** @endmethod */
```

And turn it into a Doxygen page under "Related Pages" called "Methods" that lists these two methods WITH the titles, something like:

**Doxygen output - Related Pages - Methods**:

```
Function foobar

Method 1: Multiply      <-- {} First argument turns to a number?
c = a*b;                <-- More important: This gets pulled from the code?

Method 2: Divide
d = a/b;
```

Maybe there's a better tool for this?

I've gotten so far as to produce the "Methods" page under "Related Pages" with my comments by adding this alias to the Doxyfile:

**Doxyfile**:

```
ALIASES += "method=\xrefitem method \"Method \" \"Methods\" "
```

BUT I cannot figure out a way to grab actual code to insert into the documentation...OR how to auto or manually number them (which I could preprocess)...closest I've gotten is **@code** and **groups** which was hacky and didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic numbering does not appear to be available and the closest thing to grabbing code appears to be a @snippet command, but this did not fit my schema because I don't need to use any @ref or @anchors or custom @pages, just suck in code into the documentation of an @xrefitem block.

So the answer I came up with with the best results (unless anyone else responds with something better!) is to hack the @code block in what I can only assume is an unsupported way, but happens to work perfectly for what I need (the tag numbers need to be preprocessed so I leave them as {} until documentation or use pre-commit hooks):

**Doxyfile:**

```
ALIASES += "mynotes=\verbatim My Notes:\n"
ALIASES += "endmynotes=\endverbatim"
ALIASES += "model=\xrefitem model \"Model\" \"Models\" "
ALIASES += "model{1}=\xrefitem mathmodel \"Model\" \"Models\" #\1:  "
```

**Code:**

```
/// @model{10} Do this thing with a preprocessed tag number
/// @mynotes
/// Place my notes here verbatim
/// @endmynotes
/// @code{.cpp}
    m_serr << "Bad contents!" << std::endl;
/// @endcode
```

**Output HTML documentation:**

**Model ((links to Models page)):**

#10:  Do this thing with a preprocessed tag number

```
My Notes:
   Place my notes here verbatim
```

`{.cpp}
    m_serr << "Bad contents!" << std::endl;`